# Is the distance function convex over geodesically convex sets?

Tags: convex-analysis, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and $y \in B \subset M$, where $B$ is a geodesically convex baIl. Define $f(x):=d(x,y)^2$ for $x \in B$. Is $f$ geodesically convex?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  Let $M = S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the sphere with its usual metric and $B$ its northern hemisphere.  Let $y \in B$ be a point that is close to the equator, and let $\gamma$ be a great circle arc that is a slight tilt of the equator that achieves its maximum $z$-coordinate on the other side of the sphere from $y$.  Then the (smooth) function $f \circ \gamma \colon t \mapsto d(\gamma(t), y)^2$ achieves a maximum, so cannot be convex.  Therefore, $f$ is not geodesically convex.

More precisely, let $\theta, \phi > 0$ be small positive constants such that $\theta + \phi < \frac{\pi}{2}$.  Let $y = (0, \cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ and $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, -\cos \phi \sin t, \sin \phi \sin t)$ for $t \in (0, \pi)$.  Then, one can check that $$d(\gamma(t), y)^2 = \arccos(-\cos(\theta + \phi) \sin t).$$  Furthermore, this function achieves a maximum at $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$; hence, it is not convex (alternatively, compute second derivatives).

Comment: Thank you. I guess if we restrict the domain of f to be a set contained within a hemisphere, then f would be convex on it, yes?

Comment: The function $f$ is defined on the northern hemisphere $B$, and is non-convex there.  Which "set contained within a hemisphere" are you thinking of?

Comment: Any set. To pick a particular one, choose some geodesic ball centered at I, small enough to fit inside a hemisphere. Then $f$ would be convex on that set, no? There would be no maximum, except at the boundary ofc but that doesn't disprove that $f$ is convex.

Comment: Not every set works, as I explained in my previous comment (e.g., the northern hemisphere itself wouldn't work).  In fact, even if you exclude the point where the maximum occurs, the function is non-convex in a neighborhood of the maximum.  For instance, the function $f \circ \gamma$ defined in the answer is not convex in whole interval $(0, \pi)$.